# Can a NVIDIA GT 730 support HDMI and DVI at the same time with the same resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an [ASUS-branded](https://www.asus.com/uk/Graphics-Cards/GT730SL1GD3BRK/) [GT-730](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-730/specifications) and I can see that it supports multiple monitors (2 on my card, 3 on the higher spec'd ones). I can also see that it supports a maximum resolution of 2560x1600.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does it support HDMI and DVI at the same time?
2. If so, will it support the maximum resolution for both?

I've written to ASUS but they don't seem interested in answering my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use HDMI and DVI at the same time. That's how you would setup your multi-monitors.

**Yes**, you can use the maximum resolution for both.

I would give a source but this is pure personal experience and knowledge.

**Edit:** On second thought, take a look at [this question from 2011](https://superuser.com/a/359961/498587) in which the poster says it's *highly unlikely* for a card to have outputs of different resolutions unless specifically noted. Which, your card doesn't note anything of the sort. I think you're good.

Comment: I'll put this to the test over the next week. Thanks.